# Finding the number of complex numbers satisfying $|z|=\text{max}\{|z-1|,|z+1|\}$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find the number of complex numbers satisfying $|z|=\text{max}\{|z-1|,|z+1|\}$

**My Attempt:** Let $z=x+iy$, so, $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\text{max}\{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2},\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}\}$$

Case I: $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}\implies \pm x=x-1\implies x=\frac12$

Case II: $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}\implies \pm x=x+1\implies x=-\frac12$

Does that mean if the complex numbers are lying on two lines, either $x=\frac12$ or $x=-\frac12$ then they would satisfy the required equation?

Therefore, the required number of complex numbers is infinite?

But the answer given is zero.

Can we solve this graphically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It follows from
$$
 |z-1|^2 = (x-1)^2 + y^2 = x^2 + y^2 - 2x + 1 \\
 |z+1|^2 = (x-1)^2 + y^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2x + 1 
$$
that
$$
 \max(|z-1|, |z+1|)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2|x| + 1 > x^2 + y^2 = |z|^2
$$
which shows that the equation has no solution.

*Geometrically:*
$$
 \max(|z-1|, |z+1|) = |z+1|
$$
means that the distance from $z$ to $1$ is less than or equal to the distance from $z$ to $-1$, that are exactly the points in the closed right half-plane. But points in the right half-plane are closer to the origin than to the point $-1$, so that
$$
\max(|z-1|, |z+1|) = |z+1| > |z|
$$

In the same way you can show that the equation has no solution in the (closed) left half-plane.

*With respect to your approach:* It is correct that $|z| = |z-1|$ if and only if $x=1/2$ (case I). But for those $z$ is
$$
 |z-1| < |z+1|
$$
so that does not give any solution. Similar in case II.

Comment: What a beautiful, comprehensive answer! Thanks. (In the last line, I think you meant $|z+1|\gt|z-1|?$)

Comment: @aarbee: Indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$|z| = max \{ |z-1|, |z+1|\} \implies |z| \ge |z-1|$ and $|z| \ge |z+1|$ . Summing the two equations, we have $|2z| \ge |z-1| + |z+1|$. But triangle inequality states that $|z-1| + |z+1| \ge |2z|$ so $|z-1| + |z+1| = 2|z|$. Because, $|z|$ is one of $|z-1|$ and $|z+1|$, we then deduce that $|z-1| = |z| = |z+1|$. $z$, $z-1$, and  $z+1$ are distinct and belong to the horizontal line that pass by  $z$. They cannot then be part of the circle of centre 0 and radius $|z|$ because a circle can't have more than 2 intersection points with a line. We conclude then that there's no z that satisfy our last equality.

Comment: Note that $K$ is zero for $z=1/2$. So there must be an error in your proof.

Comment: Yeah, the proof is false, Made some silly thing at the end. Just have an intuition about triangle inequality and didn't reason well. I submitted another one. @MartinR  Can you check ?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.